# How to prevent files from getting overwritten when installing using multi-instance feature

Tags: installshield, overwrite, multiple-instances

I have created a project of type `InstallScript Project`. It is a multi-instance installer and I can install multiple instances of same application.

At the time of uninstalling of any instance, I am preserving some configuration files. I have set the *`'Shared=YES'`*, *`'Uninstall=NO'`* and *`'Overwrite=Never'`* properties for components that I need to preserve. This works fine and at the time of uninstall the files that are marked as *`'Uninstall=NO'`* are preserved and not deleted.

The problem happens when I try to install a new instance. The directory to install a new instance is same as the one having preserved configuration files. But the installation Overwrites those configuration files. The property *`'Overwrite=Never'`* does not seems to have any effect. How can I prevent those files from getting overwritten.